# Dijkstra's (or other shortest path algorithm) where end node can be start node

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

The traditional* implementation of Dijkstra's does not handle this case well.  I think I've come up with some solutions that will work, but they are not particularly elegant**.  Is this is a known problem with a standard solution?

This is assuming the non-trivial solution i.e. a path like A->B->C->A rather than just A->A.

* When I say traditional I mean marking each node as visited.

** Storing the number of times each node has been visited and basing the terminating conditions on whether the end node is the start node.

Comment: If the start and end nodes are the same, Dijkstra's works trivially well: it always finds a zero-length path, which of course is the shortest one possible. What are the other constraints you're not telling us about?

Comment: You could just add a special check for this special case at the beginning of the algorithm

Comment: Can you elaborate about why a traditional implementation of Dijkstra's doesn't handle this case well? I've never had a problem with this case before.

Comment: Sorry, yes I will elaborate.  I mean assuming that you must find the non-trivial path. For example, A->B->C->A rather than A->A.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 8):

Split A into two nodes, called START and GOAL.

For any edge A->x add an edge START->x

For any edge y->A add an edge y->GOAL

Keep all other edges unchanged.

Then use normal Dijkstra to solve for the path from START to GOAL

Comment: I like that approach.  I'm gonna try it out.  Is this a standard solution to a standard problem or did you just come up with that?

Comment: It's a pretty standard approach. Remember, a "node" represents a state, not just necessarily a location. Your start node represents, say, "at position 2,3 and not fulfilling the non-triviality condition". All other nodes (including the goal) represent "at position x,y and fulfilling the non-triviality condition", including the goal node. By moving along an edge, you fulfil the non-triviality condition, and thereafter move among such nodes.

Comment: Consider how you'd find a path required to have at least seven edges. You'd have eight copies of each node (one for each <=7 number of edges), and each edge would go from a node at `edges=i` to a node at `edges=i+1`. This is a simplification of that pattern.