# Shortest distance from a node back to itself in a weighted, directed graph

Tags: c++, c, graph, nodes, dijkstra

This is driving me mad...
I have a directed graph with weighted edges between the nodes.
I need to find the shortest distance from node A and back to node A.

I've tried Djikstras algorithm and Floyd-Warshall but neither quite seem to do the trick. I'm not strong on the maths and most resources I found quickly get overly complex without explaining what I really need to do. Once I understand the steps I can code it, just struggling to find an understandable approach...

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does it mean that they "don't seem to do the trick"? Please show your code and explain what happens.. I don't really see a reason why you shouldn't be able to do this with dijkstra.

Comment: BTW, if your graph is represented by a matrix this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954743/modification-of-shortest-path-algorithm-route-from-a-node-to-itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dijkstra's (or other shortest path algorithm) where end node can be start node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408477/dijkstras-or-other-shortest-path-algorithm-where-end-node-can-be-start-node)

Comment: I don't really have any to show so far, it's more that as I work through explanations they don;t cover the case I have. Take this otherwise clearly explained one: http://www.eoinbailey.com/content/dijkstras-algorithm-illustrated-explanation it doesn't explain how to get the shortest path from A back to itself. I feel like I'm missing something obvious in my understanding.

Comment: thanks Sneftel, will go check it out.

Comment: Oh, I'm doing this in Obj-C so there's no easy collection object for a matrix, which I imagine will be problematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find the shortest non-trivial cycle containing a particular point.  You could do this by taking successive A^n, where A is the adjacency matrix, and finding the first nonzero value on the matrix diagonal corresponding to your point.  This is illustrative, but a breadth-first search will work faster.   I don't think there is a better way than the BF search, performance wise, though I can't prove that.

Here is some code that implements the search.

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/BreadthFirstDirectedPaths.java.html

You'll have to modify the termination condition, I think.

Alternatively, you could use Dijkstra's and "lift" the point in question into two different start/end points, but this isn't going to be faster for computing just one path, and makes a mess of the graph if you want many paths (point pairs).

Comment: I should have mentioned please no java code ;) OK I'll take a look. You're diagnosis of the problem seems spot on. I don't really have skills around matrix manipulation, can you explain that part a little more.

Comment: Adjacency matrix if the matrix where A_ij is 1 if there is a path from i to j, 0 otherwise.  Successive powers count the number of paths from i to j.

Comment: is there a way to do this without matrices?

Comment: The simple BF search does not find the shortest path.